# add a set to list (java)

Tags: java, arrays, list, set

I am trying to implement Kruskal's algorithm.

I have a list of sets, and I want to add a set to this list. Do I need to explicitly assign a Set before I add it to the list, or is there a way to declare the set as I add it.. code follows

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(flattened));
    Iterator iter = set.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        nodes.add(Set<>)
    }
```

nodes is a list defined as `private List<Set<Integer>> nodes;`

Comment: You mean `nodes.add(new HashSet<>());`

Comment: The `next` invocation on your `Iterator` will be of type `Integer`, as long as you don't use it raw as you're presently doing (otherwise you'd have to explicitly cast to `Integer`). It all depends on what you want to populate the `Set`s you add to your `nodes` `List` with, e.g. one-`Integer` holding `Set`s maybe...

Comment: You can also use a for-each construct to iterate your `Set`, rather than the tedious imperative `Iterator` pattern. It does the same thing without the kludge.

Comment: thanks guys!  appreciated!

Comment: @Mena I will learn how to do this next. I assume there is a way to get the value of the current set from iter? nodes.add(new HashSet<>(iter.var?));

Comment: @Mena ah it is iter.next()

Comment: @entercaspa that's the `next` invocation I was telling you about. You can simply use `for (Integer i: set) nodes.add(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{i})));` ... and spare yourself an explicit usage of `Iterator`.

Comment: I think you need Just `nodes = set.stream()
        .map(s -> new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(s)))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: ... or what YCF_L says (more elegant) if you're on Java 8+.

Comment: thanks mena, i learnt a lot from both of you, but may go with the lambda just for the elegance

Comment: @entercaspa no problem, good luck.